# How to respond politely and professionally to an email requesting information?

Tags: american-english, writing, writing-style, email, writing-advice

I have received the following email

> Hello,
>   Thank you for applying to UCB.  We would like to call you
>   briefly between the hours of 10:50 A.M. EST and noon on January 31. 
>   Please provide primary and secondary phone numbers.
>   Best regards,

How do I respond to it politely and professionally?

> Hi
>
> Please find the requested information below.
>   primary   :
>   secondary  :
>
> Thanks

Which is the professional and polite way to say that the following is the information you asked for.

> Please find the requested information below.
>   Please find the requested information as follows.
>   Kindly find the requested information below.
>   Kindly find the requested information as follows.
>   The following is the requested information.
>   Requested information are as follows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well,

> the requested information

sounds [stilted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stilted) to me (British English native speaker).

I suggest:

- Open the email with a bit more than 'Hi'. E.g.:

> Hi, thanks for getting back to me.

- Rather than 'the requested information', use 'my phone number':

> My phone numbers are 0000000 (primary) and 0000000 (secondary).

- Conclude the email with a bit more than 'Thanks':

> Looking forward to speaking with you!
>
> Best wishes,
>   Joe Bloggs.

It's more friendly that way, it reads more naturally. This level of informality is normal for business emails in British and American English.

As a check that the level of formality is appropriate, you can see how closely it matches the style of the email you're replying to:

- 'Thank you for replying' matched by 'Thanks for getting back to me'
- '*We* would like to call *you*' matched by '*my* number is' (rather than '*the* information is')
- 'Best regards' matched by 'Best wishes'.

Normal pattern for an email like this would be:

- Greeting.
- Friendly but basically content-free sentence.
- Here's the information you asked for.
- Another friendly but basically content-free sentence.
- Signoff.

I should add though that the way you have phrased it in your question above is completely comprehensible. It doesn't sound completely natural but it does succeed in getting the information across - and quite often that's entirely sufficient.